# Eclipse: Workspace Bookmark / Shortcut

Tags: eclipse

I need to switch between Worksspaces very often. The long pathnames make it difficult to find the right ws in the pull down menu.

Is there an Option or PlugIn to create bookmarks for my Worksspaces in Eclipse (in an view for example).

Or do you handle this problem?

regards

Answer (score 0):

There is a shortcut already available in `Eclipse > File (menu)`. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know but the problem is that the paths are to long in my case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you tried Add Bookmark... option under Edit menu? Does that work in your case?